# Como hacer un insert en la creacion de una vista con un union MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando crear una vista cogiendo información de dos tablas diferentes con un union pero a la hora de ponerle el valor del rol de personas no lo tengo almacenado en ninguna lado y me gustaria ponerle un valor fijo, y no se como poner un insert o como hacerlo, Yo intentado lo siguiente pero en el select me da error.

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `users` AS
SELECT 
    `usuarios`.`id` AS `id`,
    `usuarios`.`usuario` AS `username`,
    `usuarios`.`password` AS `password`,
    `usuarios`.`role_id` AS `role`
FROM
    `usuarios`
UNION 
SELECT
    `personas`.`id` AS `id`,
    `personas`.`usuario` AS `username`,
    `personas`.`contraseña` AS `password`,
    `5` AS `role`
FROM 
    `personas`
```

No se si lo que intento hacer se puede hacer o no.

Comment: Hola Daniel. A falta de saber que error es (no lo indicas en ningún lado), yo diría que quizá lo que te esté pasando es que, si role_id es una clave foránea, el valor que pones no existe en la tabla de roles, quizá el error venga de por allí...

Comment: el error es el '5' as role, en la tabla personas no tengo el campo rol, y mi idea es ponerle a todos el mismo en la creacion de la vista pero no se como

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado que quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]